# Alien name generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an assignment in my javascript class which poses a question I feel like I'm close to being able to answer, but just not quite getting there.

One thing that's confusing me is why developer tools will tell me the variable "message" is null. I can't figure it out. Everything on the assignment before this problem (which were similar problems), I've been able to get in a breeze. I may be over thinking it.

**Problem:** 
"Create an application that will generate a set of five random "alien names" when a button is clicked. These alien names must have at least one vowel in them and should have two repeated characters somewhere in the name. Example names include: 'llag', 'Uffrd', and 'Dxxi'.

These names should be shown to the user on the DOM, and replaced with new ones on subsequent button clicks."

**My Code** (have been fiddling around quite a bit with it and didn't check it before pasting, so forgive me if it's hard to navigate. Let me know how you would go about solving this with javascript.

```js
    //declares and assaigns the message (text where names will be printed) 
    var message = document.querySelector("#message");
    //declares the array and gives it 5 spots for names
    var nameArray = ["", "", "", "", ""];

    // declares the name generating function
    function rando() {
        //declares assigns name as empty for now
        var name = [];
        //randomizes length of the name
        var namelength = Math.round(Math.random() * 7) + 4;
        //declaring a vowel count
        var vowelCount = 0;
        //for loop to store each name into the array
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //for loop to decide the letters for each
            for (var i = 0; i < namelength; i++) {
                //declares boolean variable that stores whether or not the current character is a vowel using the created is Vowel() function
                var wasVowel = isVowel(name[i]);
                //if the last character was a vowel
                if (wasVowel) {
                    //counts vowels
                    vowelCount++;
                    //while loop
                    while (isVowel(name[i])) {
                        //declares the variable and assigns it to a random number between 0 and 25
                        var randomCharacterIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * 25);
                        //updates the current character based on the random variable equal to or above the unicode 97 ("a")
                        name[i] = String.fromCharCode(97 + randomCharacterIndex);
                    }
                    //if the previous character was not a vowel
                } else {
                    //while loop
                    while (isVowel(name[i]) == false) {
                        //declares variable and assigns it to random number between 0 and 25
                        var randomCharacterIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * 25);
                        //updates the current character based on the random variable equal to or above the unicode 97 ("a")
                        name[i] = String.fromCharCode(97 + randomCharacterIndex);
                    }
                }
                //adds each letter to the name
                name += name[i];
            }
            //making the first letterz
            name[0].toUpperCase();
            //adds each name to the array
            nameArray[i] = name.join("");
            //name is reset to null for the next name loop
            name = [];
        }
        //prints the names onto the DOM
        message.innerHTML = nameArray.join(", ");
    }
    

    function isVowel(character) {
        if (character == "a" || character == "e" || character == "i" || character == "o" || character == "u") {
            return true;
        } else {
            //this is the 'default'
            return false;
    }
}
```

```html
        <button onclick="rando()">Random Names</button>
        <div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please update your question to include a working demo of your code, so that we can see the issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 
[How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: It's null because you have to HTML here.  Where is your HTML?  Also, use the or operator `||` in your `isVowel` function and get that done in one `if` statement.  Or better yet, use `some`.

Comment: hey, I added my HTML to an answer I posted. sorry about that. Thanks. I will shorten the isVowel function and use || instead of "or". I don't know why I'm having so much trouble on this

Comment: One problem you have in your code is that you are using the same index in your loops `for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  for (var i = 0; i < namelength; i++) {` You need to change one of those `ì` variables to something else.
`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following approach

1. Generate random name length
2. Generate random double character position
3. Generate obligatory vowel position that doesn't intersect the two repeating
   characters
4. Build word, following the set up rules and generating random     characters accordingly

   ```
   var message = document.querySelector("#message");

   function rando() {

      message.innerHTML = "";

       for (var j=0;j<5;j++)
       {
         var name = "";
         var namelength = Math.round(Math.random() * 7) + 4;
         var pairPosition = Math.round(Math.random() * (namelength-1));
         var obligatoryVowelPos = Math.round(Math.random() * (namelength-1));



         while(obligatoryVowelPos == pairPosition || obligatoryVowelPos == (pairPosition+1))
         obligatoryVowelPos = Math.round(Math.random() * (namelength-1));


          for (var i =0;i<namelength;i++) {


           if (i==pairPosition)
           {
               var character = generateRandomLetter();
               name = name + character + character;
               i++;
           }
           else if (i==obligatoryVowelPos)
           {
              name = name + generateVowel();
           }
           else
           {
              name = name+generateRandomLetter();
           }

           name = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);

       //prints the names onto the DOM

       }
       message.innerHTML += name + "<br>";
       }

   }

   function generateVowel()
   {
         var aeiou = Math.round(Math.random()*4)+1;

         switch (aeiou)
         {
             case 1:return 'a';break;
             case 2:return 'e';break;
             case 3:return 'i';break;
             case 4:return 'o';break;
             case 5:return 'u';break;
         }
   }

   function generateRandomLetter()
   {
       var randomCharacterIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * 25);
       return String.fromCharCode(97 + randomCharacterIndex);
   }
   ```

Although not required, you could also use your original isVowel function to prevent double vowels when the code enters, or to add a vowel to the word if no vowels had been added after the word creation loop ends. It's really up to you, this code already solves your issue.

Comment: Where is `y` vowel? Moreover I think you want the modulo, not multiplying by 4.

Comment: `y` can be considered either a vowel or a consonant according to context and even language; since OP didn't include it in his own `isVowel()` function I didn't consider it. And no, it's *. Unlike C `rand()` method, Javascript's `Math.random()` returns a float value between 0 and 1, which will multiply and result in a fraction of the number 4. It must be rounded so that we have an integer, and then 1 is added so that we never get zero.